# Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: node.js

Context:

I've created what I called a softmodem-poetry machine, using two softmodems transmitters to transmit synchronously two different twitter streams at the same baud rate, creating an entanglement of quasi-gibberish/quasi-legible signals coming both from softmodem 1 and softmodem 2. These programs were running three months ago.

Problem:

When I try running these programs now, I have this `Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed` as soon as I connect to my socket.

Here's the relevant code I think:

```
twit.stream("statuses/filter", { track: randomTitle}, function(stream) {
      stream.on("data", function(data) {
        socket.emit("tweet", data.text);
        child.stdin.write(data.text);
      });
});`
```

Here's the entire code: https://github.com/cyruslk/twitter_minimodem/blob/master/app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grant wrx access to log files, like chmod 777.